# canvas restarts after 60 seconds

Tags: javascript, canvas

Im trying to do a solar system with canvas. Everything works well except i want to make each planet move at different speed. However if i use setInterval and ctx.rotate after 60 seconds the whole canvas restarts and every planet starts from the beggining again.

```
var sun = new Image();
var mercury = new Image();
var venus = new Image();

function init(){
    sun.src = 'sun.png';
    mercury.src = 'mercury.png';
    venus.src = 'venus.png';
    setInterval(draw,10);
}

function draw() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,2000,2000);
    ctx.save();  
    ctx.translate(1000,1000); 
    // MERCURY
    var time = new Date();
    ctx.rotate( ((2*Math.PI)/30)*time.getSeconds() + ((2*Math.PI)/30000)*time.getMilliseconds() );
    ctx.translate(105,0);
    ctx.save(); 
    ctx.rotate( -(((2*Math.PI)/3)*time.getSeconds() + ((2*Math.PI)/3000)*time.getMilliseconds() ) ); 
    ctx.drawImage(mercury,-15,-15,30,30);
    ctx.restore(); 
    ctx.restore();
    // VENUS
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(1000,1000);
    ctx.rotate( ((2*Math.PI)/120)*time.getSeconds() + ((2*Math.PI)/120000)*time.getMilliseconds() ); 
    ctx.translate(150,0); 
    ctx.save();
    ctx.rotate( -(((2*Math.PI)/3)*time.getSeconds() + ((2*Math.PI)/3000)*time.getMilliseconds() ));
    ctx.drawImage(venus,-35,-35,70,70);
    ctx.restore(); 
    ctx.restore();
    ctx.drawImage(sun,900,900,200,200);  
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/Butkis/pen/bpGqXz)

scroll down a little. After 60 seconds Venus will appear on the other side. 
How to make this animation to never ever stop or restart after some time?
Thanks.

BTW. The whole problem is because of the Math.PI calculations, I guess, but i have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: can you provide your code as snippet or in plunker or jsbin?

Comment: @PavanTeja here you go http://codepen.io/Butkis/pen/bpGqXz scroll down a little. After 60 seconds it will restart and venus will move to the other side instantly

Comment: My guess is it has to do with your Pi math.

Comment: @JaredFarrish yeah you are right, however i have no idea what code to use instead of it or how to fix the issue.

Comment: Use `console.log()` to see what values are being plugged in: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxNWzp?editors=0010 That will at least tell you what value is occurring. In this case, it goes from `-125.65951735338693` to `-0.014660765716752367`.

Comment: Here's a capture with the dynamic values as they change: `-(((2*3.141592653589793)/3)*59 + ((2*3.141592653589793)/3000)*992) = -125.64695098277257` to `(((2*3.141592653589793)/3)*0 + ((2*3.141592653589793)/3000)*3) = -0.006283185307179586` Note how the first goes to zero, and the second goes from `-125` to `3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `time.getSeconds()` as it will always give you a value between 0 and 59, so everything will repeat after a minute.

A solution would be to calculate the time elapsed and calculate the angles from that.

```
var startTime = Math.floor(Date.now())

# in draw:
var t = Math.floor(Date.now()) - startTime;

ctx.rotate( ((2*Math.PI)/30)*t/1000 + ((2*Math.PI)/30000)*t );
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwNOQG?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the actual clock seconds and milliseconds to set the angle.  When the clock seconds hit 0, then the angle of Venus goes back to 0 :).  If you base the planet's position on absolute time rather than per minute time, there is no reset.  I updated your codepen to illustrate: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyowbw?editors=0010.  I used the getSeconds() of the startTime to offset the starting position of Venus, so that both planets don't start at the same angular position (0).

```
var sun = new Image();
var venus = new Image();
var mercury = new Image();
var startTime = new Date();  //<-- Capture a reference time
function init(){
  sun.src = 'sun.png';
  venus.src = 'venus2.gif';
  mercury.src = 'mercurySm.png';
  setInterval(draw,10); 
}
function draw() {
   var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

   ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-over';
   ctx.clearRect(0,0,2000,2000); 
   ctx.save();  
   ctx.translate(1000,1000);  

   // MERCURY
   var time = new Date(); 
   var timeDiff = time.getTime() - startTime.getTime();  //<- get the difference in milliseconds from your reference time.

   ctx.rotate(((2*Math.PI)/30000)*timeDiff);  //<-use the reference timediff to set the planet angle
   ctx.translate(105,0); 
   ctx.save(); 
   ctx.rotate( -(((2*Math.PI)/3)*time.getSeconds() + ((2*Math.PI)/3000)*time.getMilliseconds() ) );
   ctx.drawImage(mercury,-15,-15,30,30);
   ctx.restore(); 
   ctx.restore();

   // VENUS
   ctx.save();
   ctx.translate(1000,1000);
   ctx.rotate(((2*Math.PI)/120000)*timeDiff + ((2*Math.PI)/120)*startTime.getSeconds()); //<-use the reference timediff to set the planet angle, and use the reference time to set the angle offset.
   ctx.translate(150,0);
   ctx.save();
   ctx.rotate( -(((2*Math.PI)/3)*time.getSeconds() + ((2*Math.PI)/3000)*time.getMilliseconds() ));
   ctx.drawImage(venus,-35,-35,70,70);
   ctx.restore();
   ctx.restore();

   ctx.drawImage(sun,900,900,200,200);  
}
```